# Material-ui IconButton edge properties not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to put the delete icon at the right side of the screen and using the `edge= "end"` does not work.

sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-silence-vwfoe?file=/src/App.js:0-1733

These are the codes:

```
 <Card className={classes.root}>
    <Typography variant="h5">Announcement </Typography>
    <Grid container justify="flex-end">
      {/* <Link to="#" className={classes.link}>
        <Button>
          <AddIcon /> Add Announcement
        </Button>
      </Link> */}
    </Grid>
    <Grid container justify="flex-start">
      <Card className={classes.root}>
        <CardHeader
          title="Name of Announcement"
          action={
            <IconButton aria-lable="edit" style={{ color: "green" }}>
              <EditIcon />
            </IconButton>
          }
        />
        <CardContent>Schedule</CardContent>
        <CardActions>
          <IconButton
            aria-label="delete"
            edge="end"
            style={{ color: "#c70000 " }}
          >
            <DeleteIcon edge="end" />
          </IconButton>
        </CardActions>
      </Card>
    </Grid>
  </Card>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by setting `CardActions`'s style prop `justifyContent` to `flex-end` in this way:

```
...
<CardActions style={{ justifyContent: "flex-end" }}> //<-- add this style 
   <IconButton
      aria-label="delete"
      edge="end"
      style={{ color: "#c70000 " }}
>
     <DeleteIcon />
   </IconButton>
</CardActions>
...
```

And the result is:

[image]

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-rgb-m5wqf?file=/src/App.js) your codesandbox modified.